# Admitad API Client authorization

Tags: java, android, api

I try to xplain better my question.

On my APP, I am developing coupon section and I would to use Admitad API for the coupon section.

This is the official page for Admitad API:
https://www.admitad.com/en/developers/doc/api_en/auth/auth-index/

I would authorize my APP to get the informations I require to show coupon code on my APP automatically from Admitad directly.

On my APP, I have added a JAVA file class witht his code:

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.admitad.com/token/");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
String response = new Scanner(in).useDelimiter("\\A").next();

public APIAuthenticationShareasale() throws IOException {
}
```

To get the coupon from my Admitad account, I have to add cliet_authorization on my APP java class.

Could someone explain me how add username, password, etc?

Thank you in adavance

---

EDIT:

I got some detail more. Before, I need to get access token. I have all details: client_seret, client_id etc.

I added the authorization on manifest:

Could someone help me to create the token request?

Comment: Your question is unclear, please read the guidelines on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question. I woul suggest you also have a look at `jackson` class `ObjectMapper` that is used to serialize objects, then you can create a class with required fields and serialize it while sending your HTTP request

Comment: I tried to expalin better my question :)